# Dynamic statement for Yesterday in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I run the below query to check if something ran the previous day. The below query works, but I have to change the date each day to get the results I want. I've tried multiple things that I've found that seem like they ***should*** return results, but they don't quite seem to work.

```
select * from Linking_Results 
where Evaluated between '2015-02-04 00:00:01.001' and '2015-02-04 23:59:00.999'
and Linked = '1' order by Evaluated
```

So my question is, how do I make a dynamic statement for yesterday and keep from having to change the date daily?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server 2008?  They are very different products. @paul are you sure about removing SQL Server 2008 from the title?

Comment: @bluefeet I went with MySQL because of the tag & upvoted answer. Original title was 'My SQL Server 2008' which was confusing.

Comment: @paul Unfortunately many times the tags and title are typically wrong.  Many people refer to `mysql server` and mean **my** `sql server`.

Comment: @bluefeet At least this way, the question title, tag and top answer are all 'in sync'

Comment: @paul It'd be better to wait for the OP to clarify though, IMO

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is what I meant to put... Sorry, I have infant brain at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dateadd` and `getdate` functions.

```
declare @start datetime,
        @end datetime

-- subtract one day and cast it as a date to drop the time portion
select  @start = cast(dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) as date)
-- add one day and subtract 3ms to get the end of yesterday (apparently SQL rounds)
select  @end = dateadd(ms, -3, dateadd(day, 1, @start))
```

The values would then be

```
2015-02-04 00:00:00.000
2015-02-04 23:59:59.997
```

and you can do a between on these two variables. Since you use `between` which is inclusive, you need to account for the time portion. You could change the where clause to go to the next day and do an exclusive check on @end

```
select @end = dateadd(day, 1, @start)

where Evaluated >= @start and Evaluated < @end
```

Comment: I get the following when I run it:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'current_date'.

Comment: @Gareth, that answer was for MySQL. It's a little more complicated in MSSQL apparently. I've updated it with an example.